# Can I get a PDF from `.lvt` files to visually verify the output?

Tags: package-writing, l3build

I'm trying to write regression tests with the `l3build` system.  I know how to use `l3build save` to make a `.tlg` file from an `.lvt` file so that future tests can be compared against what's presumed to be a successful outcome.

But I can't figure out how to make l3build generate a PDF from a `.lvt` file, so I can look at the output and verify it's doing what I want.  It seems like that's a natural step in the process, before running `l3build save`.

I also know how to make an `.lvt` file and an `.lve` file so that `l3build check` can verify that the test output is equal to the expected output.  So I can write the `.lve` to use lower-level code to generate what I want the `.lvt` file to generate.  But I can't see the PDF output from `.lve` files either.

Here's an MWE (let's call it `testfiles/test.lvt`):

```
\input regression-test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
\START
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_tmp_box
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmp_box {$\R$}
\box_show:N \l_tmp_box
\ExplSyntaxOff
\END
\end{document}
```

Then `l3build save test` produces `test.tlg` in `testfiles/` and `build/test`, but no PDF file in either directory.

Comment: _if_ your lvt produces a document then you can always run it by hand to see the pdf, but if it just uses `\showbox` or `\typeout` tests or ends with `\END` rather than `\end{document}` then there may be no pdf

Comment: the pdf should be in the build folder after l3build save or l3build check.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @Ulrike  Thanks, that's important information.  It looks like I should avoid `\END` if I want PDF output.

Comment: well you certainly need a test file that actually creates a pdf ;-)

Comment: I think I understand now.  I added an answer that creates both `.tlg` and `.pdf` files.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so I learned from the comments that I need to avoid `\END` because that short-circuits the tex run, and I have to make sure some (non-log) output is generated.

I removed `\END` from the MWE above.  And to make sure I generated some output, I added a `\box_use:N` line to the `\box_show:N` line.  The `show` one only describes the box, and that only gets saved in the `.log` file.  The `use` one actually puts the box in the output stream.

So my test now looks like:

```
\input regression-test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\START
\box_new:N \l_tmp_box
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmp_box {$\R$}
\box_show:N \l_tmp_box
\box_use:N \l_tmp_box
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Now `l3build save test` creates the file `build/test/test.tlg` that looks like this:

```
This is a generated file for the l3build validation system.
Don't change this file in any respect.
> \box...=
\hbox(6.88889+0.0)x7.22223
.\mathon
.\U/msb/m/n/10 R
.\mathoff
! OK.
<argument> \l_tmp_box
l. ...\box_show:N \l_tmp_box
[1
] (test.aux)
```

It also creates `build/test/test.pdf` with the contents of `\l_tmp_box` in it.  And I didn't have to repeat the tested code, only one extra line to handle the box in two different ways.